# how to automatically generate values ​for object attributes in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, oop, intellisense

**SITUATION**: When you finish creating a class, you start trying to see if everything is working fine. the classic way: `Person p1 = new Person(name="someCasualName", lastName="someCasualLastName", age = casualNumber);`

and do some tests.

But imagine you have a class with a lot of attributes. and you need a large number of objects to make some tests. It takes you a lot of time to write: Person p1 = ....
Person p2 = ....
Person p3 = ...
immagine you need 20 or more Person objects!

**GOAL**: an intellisense or extension to generate an X number of objects. (not necessary with "real data". I mean, it's not necessary to generate names like David or Adam.. but I'm fine with casual names like Pstse or Latssr).

*just immagine with me writing Person Xnumber and clicking tap key and you see 20 generate objects from the Person class. That's what I want....*

**EXPLANATION WTIH CODE:**
Instead of writing something like that by myself, I want an intellisense to do it for me

```
Person Person1 = new Person("OSH3S", "Adkm", "Rshgs", "adtsel@gmail.com", "+32526235263");
Person Person2 = new Person("W5SFS", "Ietg", "Lcxy", "axys@gmail.com", "+362345263");
Person Person3 = new Person("O566S", "Ssh", "Jajis", "saxlr@gmail.com", "+3252999263");
Person Person4 = new Person("OX5RS", "Axxt", "Amak", "lsapori@gmail.com", "+32006235263");
Person Person5 = new Person("STK00", "Pjovik", "Rakok", "asgxee@gmail.com", "+32511235263");
```

Comment: Use a fake data generator like https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus

Comment: The question is not about data, but about syntax.

Comment: Use a loop, add your `Person` objects to a `List<Person>` and just have a method that generates your random data.

Comment: But it will take some time to write it. I want visual studio to do this with just a 'key click' like the functionality that VS provides to generate the constructor of a class

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry that visual studio doesn't have the functionality you want. You can propose this new feature to the [developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=suggestion).